# consuming a WCF Service proxy using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I am trying to call WCF from my asp.net application using Jquery. 
I have a WCF service called MYservice hosted on IIS. 
I have an another application called MyWeb and I created a proxy to MYservice. Now I am trying to consume the MYservice using jquery. How can I achieve that.
Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are few things that you should take into consideration if you want to consume your WCF service directly from javascript:

- client side javascript doesn't exist alone. It is hosted somewhere. In your case I guess it is hosted in an ASP.NET application. This ASP.NET application is hosted on a given domain. So the first thing that you should consider is the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that is built into browsers. It basically forbids you from sending AJAX requests to anything that is different than the domain hosting the javascript. So in your case you must be hosting the WCF service inside the same application
- The second thing that you should consider is that javascript AJAX requests usually do standard HTTP requests such as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. They don't do SOAP. So if you want to consume your WCF service from javascript the easiest would be to use a `webHttpBinding`. Here's [one article](http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/consuming-wcf-services-using-jquery-json/) that might get you started.